# Print content of jquery dialog to a printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, browser, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following jQueryUI dialog.  How can I print the content of the dialog?  The content could be any HTML such as a table, image, etc.  There were several earlier answers to this question,however, they appear to be out of date.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#openDialog").click(function(){$("#myDialog").dialog('open')});
                $( "#myDialog" ).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    buttons: {Ok: function() {alert('print');}}
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="openDialog">Click</button>
        <div id="myDialog" title="My Dialog">
            <p>Print this text!</p>
            <img alt="And print this image" src="myImg.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what do you want? Do you want to print contents from the modal into a separate `div#` or do you want to print your modal `p` and `img` (or whatever) when you click `Ok` button, into an alert window as I see in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed my own plugin with code is below, and a live example is located at http://jsfiddle.net/fyu4P/embedded/result/.

On FF 26.0, it works, however, after printing a couple of times, FF asks the user if popups should be disabled which I wish not to happen.  Also, it doesn't work with older IE, and likely other browsers.  Don't worry, when printing, you still need to click the operating system print dialog, so you won't waste any paper!  I've asked https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39235/critique-of-jquery-plugin-which-will-print-to-a-printer-an-element-or-a-jqueryui for any recommendations.

Actual Plugin:

```
/*
* jQuery printIt
* Print's the selected elements to the printer
* Copyright Michael Reed, 2014
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        elems           :null, //Element to print HTML
        copy_css        :false,//Copy CSS from original element
        external_css    :null  //New external css file to apply
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options)
            elems=$(settings.elems);
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    var iframe   = document.createElement('iframe');
                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                    $(iframe).load(function(){
                        elems.each(function(){
                            iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
                        });
                        if(settings.copy_css) {
                            var arrStyleSheets = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
                            for (var i = 0; i < arrStyleSheets.length; i++){
                                iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(arrStyleSheets[i].cloneNode(true));
                            }
                            var arrStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
                            for (var i = 0; i < arrStyle.length; i++){    
                                iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(arrStyle[i].cloneNode(true));
                            }
                        }
                        if(settings.external_css) {
                            var style  = document.createElement("link")
                            style.rel  = 'stylesheet';
                            style.type = 'text/css';
                            style.href = settings.external_css;
                            iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(style);
                        }
                        var script   = document.createElement('script');
                        script.type  = 'text/javascript';
                        script.text  = 'window.print();';
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(script);
                        $(iframe).hide();
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            //Anything else I should do here?
            delete settings;
            return this.each(function () {});
        }
    };

    $.fn.printIt = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.printIt');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery)
);
```

To configure:

```
$(function () {
    $("#openDialog").click(function () {
        $("#myDialog").dialog('open')
    });
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#printIt').printIt({
        elems: $("#myDialog"),
        copy_css: true,
        external_css: 'test2.css'
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, man thanks for you plugin, i have a recommendation, u can remove the event **Click** in the plugin, because this cause that you have to do a double click for can print. Well Thanks =)

Comment: For Google Chrome this solution doesn't work. The result is an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a printable area, and puts modal html into it.

```
$(function () {
    $("#openDialog").click(function () {
        $("#myDialog").dialog('open')
    });
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function (e) {
                $('#divToPrint').html($(this)[0].innerHTML).printArea();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You need to create a new `<div id="divToPrint"></div>` if you want to not display the new div, just use `style="display: none;"`

Then when you press CTRL+P it will print what you created...

Comment: Thanks!  Is `printArea()` a plugin?  I get `$(...).html(...).printArea is not a function`.  Anyway to do it without pressing CTRL+P?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.....and call your div id. You should be good to go.

```
buttons: { 
            "Print": function() { 
                $("#dialog").printArea(); 
            },
            "Close": function() { 
               $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit? Code-only answers are frowned upon on the whole.