# hide label on my page and display it on print page' (when click button) using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

We design a website using asp.net with the help of Jquery we are showing some information in modal popup. It is successfully working. Now my question is What we are  showing some  information using modal popup,  we need that information in print preview page and we need print that too. But now only link button is displaying in print preview page, **but we need both what we are showing whole page include  modal popup information also in print preview page and hard copy too**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print content of jquery dialog to a printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001831/print-content-of-jquery-dialog-to-a-printer)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are several ways to achieve this.
but for my opinion the best one is to do this via css:

There are two options:

1. Add own css for "print" state;

Add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="print">
```

Also you can specify `media="..."` for some other stuff like projection and etc.

2. Use media queries;

Simple:

```
@media print {
   //override your stiles here, display: block or whatever
}
```

The idea to override all necessary classes inside this block.